# TOKEN structure in Kernel

Tags: debugging, c, windbg, kernel-mode, process

I would like to know how `WinDbg` extracts all the user, group, privilege information about a process from a `token` when given the `!token 0xaddress` command so I can implement it in my driver code.

Example output of `!token 0xaddress` command
[image: user_infor_output]

According to [this](https://www.nirsoft.net/kernel_struct/vista/EPROCESS.html) site token has the `EX_FAST_REF` structure which has a definition like this:

```
typedef struct EX_FAST_REF {
       union {
              PVOID Object;
              ULONG RefCnt : 3;
              ULONG Value;
         };
 }EX_FAST_REF, *PEX_FAST_REF
```

`Object` field points to the address of the token, the `Value` field holds the fist 4 bytes from the token address. I could not find the info I need from these fields but when I investigate the token address a little bit I am beginning to see strings like `uid`. What is the type of structure windbg uses to get all of this information? (Both debugger and debuggee have 32 bit architecture).

[image: uid_from_address]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Token you've used, the link, is not the Token structure you're searching for.
This is the structure
https://www.nirsoft.net/kernel_struct/vista/TOKEN.html

Comment: I am marking this as an accepted answer. Since it answered my question. But when I try to place all of the needed structures by TOKEN structure compiler gives a syntax error(Code 2061). Is there a library where all of these structures are predefined?

Comment: The definition of structures on OS version based. It's different from Win7 to Win10 to x86 to x64... Unfortunately the **moonsols** which was provided by Microsoft is not available anymore. There you could find the exact structure based on the version.

Comment: @EWD-0- You can use https://www.vergiliusproject.com/ as alternative to moonsols. It contains kernel structures from WinXP to Win10.